# Gradle Increment VersionCode for Release Build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Below is the code I put at the end of build.gradle file, trying to increment versionCode for staging release build. However, when I run `./gradlew assembleDebug` versionCode gets increases as well.. what have I done wrongly?

```
task('increaseVersionCode') {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++versionCode + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateStagingReleaseBuildConfig') {
        println "Task Name [$task.name]"
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything a task should do when it gets executed needs to go into a *task action*. A task action is added with `doLast { /* code goes here */ }`. Code outside a task action *configures* the task, and gets run on every build invocation as part of "parsing" the build script.

Comment: so the way I define a task is wrong? I should put the action inside doLast{} ?

Comment: Yes it's wrong. In this particular case, the whole body of the task declaration has to be wrapped with `doLast { ... }`, because it's all about execution (not configuration).